# Q Promises not resolving as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I am building a script that is using glob and q. I wanted to be able to send it a string `"src/**/*.js"`, and have it call a function on each path name. I wanted to extend this so I could pass it an array of globs like `["stage1/**/*.js", "stage2/**/*.js"]`, and even `[["stage1/**/*.js", "stage2/**/*.js"], "stage3/**/*.js"]`, essentially letting me arbitrarily define order dependencies, without actually caring about the order within the groups themselves.

I came up with the following script:

```js
var Q = require("q");
var glob = require("glob");

function type(value) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(value);
}

function iterate(spec, options, callback) {
  if (spec instanceof Array) {
    // convert spec into list of promises
    var promises = spec.map(function(spec) {
      return iterate(spec, options, callback);
    });

    // reduce promises into chain
    return promises.reduce(function(previous, current) {
      return previous.then(current);
    });
  } else if (type(spec) === "[object String]") {
    return Q.nfcall(glob, spec, options)
      .then(function(files) {
        // map files into list of promises
        var promises = files.map(function(file) {
          return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            try {
              callback(file, resolve);
            } catch (error) {
              reject(error);
            }
          });
        });

        // wait for all promises to complete
        return Q.all(promises);
      });
  } else {
    throw new Error("The value passed in must be a string, or array of strings.");
  }
};

module.exports = function(spec, options, callback, finished) {
  options = options || {};
  callback = callback || function(file, resolved) {
    resolved();
  };
  finished = finished || function(error) {
    error ? finished(error) : finished(null);
  };

  iterate(spec, options, callback)
    .then(function() {
      finished(null);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      finished(error);
    })
    .done();
};
```

It uses recursion to queue things, and then exposes a normal-looking nodejs interface. This is the index.js file that uses the module above.

```js
var example = require("./lib/example");

var files = [
  [
    "./node_modules/q/**/*.json",
    "./node_modules/q/**/*.js"
  ],
  "./node_modules/glob/*.json",
  "./node_modules/glob/*.js"
];

example(files, {}, listFile, finished);

function listFile(filename, done) {
  console.log(filename);
  done();
}

function finished(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("finished");
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell documentation-wise this should work. But, if I use a glob that returns a bunch of files, the "finished" text will print before all of the files print out.

I thought it was the use of `Q.all()`, and some kind of failure to check for finishing. But actually the `Q.all()` seems to be working, there's never a file missed. Strangely, chaining with the `then` operation in the `promises.reduce()`, from what I can tell, doesn't seem to be waiting until the other promises finish. And even seems to be ignoring the order of the `then` chain entirely...

I thought maybe `console.log` was acting asynchronously, but according to other posts, in my situation, `console.log` should be a synchronous operation... Can someone here see what I am misunderstanding about this, or spot a bug that I've missed?

Comment: just tested it, "finished" always displays at the end. (q@1.4.1, node v5.1)

Comment: I should have mentioned that. Yes, when you run it as is, the finish runs at the end. But if you change `"./node_modules/glob/*.js"` to `"./node_modules/glob/**/*.js"`, finished prints before all the output. Basically if the glob returns any non-trivial size of files it keeps showing finished before the output of all the files.

Comment: ah ok. I see. I think the problem might be that in your iterate function's if/else clause the two promises aren't chained to one another. let me test it out..

Comment: node v4.2.3 Q v1.4.1 (but it has the same thing on nodejs 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your iterator function's if else clause could return two separated promises:

```
function iterate(spec, options, callback) {
  if (spec instanceof Array) {
    return PromiseA;
  } else if (type(spec) === "[object String]") {
    return PromiseB;
  }
};
```

They need to be chained as well:

```
function iterate(spec, options, callback, previousPromise) {
  if (spec instanceof Array) {
    previousPromise.then(function(){
      return doStuff();
    })
  } else if (type(spec) === "[object String]") {
    previousPromise.then(function(){
      return doStuff();
    })
  }
  return previousPromise;
};
```

I've come up with this, but I'mnot familiar with Q (mainly how to get a resolved promise) so I'm sure you could improve on it:

```
function getPromise(){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
}

function iterate(spec, options, callback, promiseChain) {
    console.log('spec:', spec);
    promiseChain = promiseChain || getPromise();
    if (spec instanceof Array) {
        promiseChain = promiseChain.then(function() {
            return spec.reduce(function(promiseChain, spec) {
                return promiseChain.then(function() {
                    return iterate(spec, options, callback, promiseChain);
                });
            }, getPromise());
        })
    } else if (type(spec) === "[object String]") {
        promiseChain = promiseChain.then(function() {
            return Q.nfcall(glob, spec, options)
                .then(function(files) {
                    console.log('files:', files);
                    // map files into list of promises
                    var promises = files.map(function(file) {
                        return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                            try {
                                callback(file, resolve);
                            } catch (error) {
                                reject(error);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    // wait for all promises to complete
                    return Q.all(promises);
                });
        });
    } else {
        throw new Error("The value passed in must be a string, or array of strings.");
    }
    return promiseChain;
};
```

Comment: OK, I don't fully understand why my code isn't building a valid chain yet. But now I have something to compare against. Thank you for figuring this out.